# How to restart webkitSpeechRecognition without asking for microphone permission?

Tags: webkitspeechrecognition

I used `webkitSpeechRecognition` to record user voice and using `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` speaks to the user, however, there has a problem for when the system speaking to the user, it will also record voice.

If I stop the recognition and restart, it will ask microphone permission again. If it has any ideas to pause the recognition and resumed when the speaking is finished?

or using `Recognition.stop()` and `Recognition.start()` without asking microphone permission again?

Answer (score -1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Methods) theSpeechRecognition API already has those methods:

> `SpeechRecognition.abort()`
>
> Stops the speech recognition service from listening to incoming audio, and doesn't attempt to return a SpeechRecognitionResult.
>
> `SpeechRecognition.start()`
>
> Starts the speech recognition service listening to incoming audio with intent to recognize grammars associated with the current SpeechRecognition.
>
> `SpeechRecognition.stop()`
>
> Stops the speech recognition service from listening to incoming audio, and attempts to return a SpeechRecognitionResult using the audio captured so far.

Comment: Yeah i see, however, it does not fixed my problem